# jQuery data-attribute selector doesn't work on click

Tags: javascript, jquery

After `click` and change `data-visible` value, I can't select `data-visible` with new value.

JS:

```
$('#imageUploadAction').on('click', function(e) {
 $('#imageUploadAction').html('Close');
 $('.image-upload-action').toggleClass('h-100 show');
 $('#imageUploadAction').attr('data-visible', 'show');
 $('.image-upload-action-btn').removeClass('d-none');
 $('.image-upload-action-btn').addClass('d-block');
});
$('#imageUploadAction[data-visible="show"]').on('click', function(e) {
 console.log('ok');
});
```

HTML:

```
<div class="image-upload-action d-flex align-items-center flex-column">
  <a id="imageUploadAction" href="javascript:void(0)" data-visible="hide">edit</a>
  <div class="image-upload-action-btn d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center mt-auto d-block">
    data
  </div>
</div>
```

How can I fix this problem?

[Demo Here](https://jsfiddle.net/wa5njy9k/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You rather put the value of data-visible in string and check it with a if

```js
$('#imageUploadAction').on('click', function(e) {
  let getStatut = $(this).attr('data-visible');
  
  console.clear();
  console.log(getStatut);
  
  if (getStatut == "hide") {
   $(this).html('Close').attr('data-visible', 'show');
   $(this).parent('.image-upload-action').toggleClass('h-100 show');
   $(this).next('.image-upload-action-btn').removeClass('d-none').addClass('d-block');
  } else {
    // show
   $(this).html('Open').attr('data-visible', 'hide');
   $(this).parent('.image-upload-action').toggleClass('h-100 hide');
   $(this).next('.image-upload-action-btn').removeClass('d-block').addClass('d-none');  
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="image-upload-action d-flex align-items-center flex-column">
  <a id="imageUploadAction" href="javascript:void(0)" data-visible="hide">edit</a>
  <div class="image-upload-action-btn d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center mt-auto d-block">
    data
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `$(this).find('.image-upload-action-btn').removeClass('d-none').addClass('d-block');` This element does not exist yet.

Comment: I edited my code. Use next() instead : https://api.jquery.com/next/ and parent() for '.image-upload-action' : https://api.jquery.com/parent/

Answer (score 0):

#### The element does not exist yet

At the time you add a click handler for `#imageUploadAction[data-visible="show"]` no element with this selector exists.

Use this to bind the click handler to `.image-upload-action` and any future element with the selector:

```js
$('.image-upload-action').on('click', '#imageUploadAction[data-visible="show"]', function(e) {
 console.log('ok');
});
```

See jQuery documentation here:
https://api.jquery.com/on/#on-events-selector-data

Comment: Just small issue, this will trigger that click event on the first click which might not be something OP wants.

Comment: if you change main value of `data-visible` to `show` u can see the element exist! The problem is: when we change `data-visible` to `show`, the new `data-visible` doesn't exist.

Comment: My point was that this click event on `#imageUploadAction[data-visible="show"]` will be executed on the initial click of `edit` based on the current code, even though the initial `data-visible` is set to false. So it could be that OP doesn't want to run this click event that logs ok on the initial click on edit, because `data-visible` is then changed to value `show` in the code and then maybe only on the future click this second click event should work.

Comment: But I'm just guessing here

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#imageUploadAction').on('click', function() {
    if($(this).data('visible') === 'show') {
        console.log('data visible is show');
        $(this).html('Edit').data('visible', 'hide');
    } else {
        console.log('data visible is hide');
        $(this).html('Close').data('visible', 'show');
    }
    $('.image-upload-action').toggleClass('h-100 show');
    $('.image-upload-action-btn').toggleClass('d-block d-none');
});
```

I'm assuming you are toggling the actions between Edit and Close. I have simplified your code and handled data attributes using [jQuery data](https://api.jquery.com/data/) and chained multiple jquery methods on the common selector. You can replace this and check in your jsFiddle.
Multiple click handlers are not ideal to have, so just use one and check the value of the attribute and make decisions based on it. You can add else if to add more values other than show and hide.